# Slack modal is not cleared from a Updated view

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands

I have modal flow in my Slack App. I have some issues with the end of the flow however.
Basic idea of the flow. You get a Modal, you do a selection, you get another modal, you perform an action and then Modal disappears.

I have tried two different ways both with problems but with different result

Flow 1: response_action: "update"

1. You press a button on home tab that opens a modal with bot.views.open
2. You make a selection
3. In the response I send {response_action: 'update', view: }
4. User gets the new Modal without any errors. They then click a button.
5. Now I would like the modal to disappear. So on the result of the action I send {response_action: 'clear'}
6. Nothing happens :(. I would like the modal to disappear of course :)

Flow 2: bot.views.update

1. You press a button on home tab that opens a modal with bot.views.open
2. You make a selection
3. I create the same view as above but I run bot.views.update{view_id: , view: }
4. New view comes up however it has an error in the top: We had some trouble connecting. Try again?
5. Now I would like the modal to disappear. So on the result of the action I send {response_action: 'clear'}
6. Nothing happens :(. I would like the modal to disappear of course :)

So second flow has annoying error but same result with not disappearing.
Feels like Im missing something here.

Somebody have an Idea what Im missing?

Comment: After more experimenting it seems its the Overflow Menu that is actually causing this. A reply to an Overflow Menu action cant be a response_type: "clear". Which of course is really annoying. Any body have a take on this?